# Sorting a dataframe based values on a list

Tags: sorting

I have a dataframe that contains some routing data sorted in three columns. The first column "driver" has the driver ID. The second column "from" shows the point that this segemnt of the route starts at, and the third column "to" shows where that segment ends at. So following the rows for each driver, you show go from the start point through some intermediate point until you reach the end point. I also have two lists, one has the starting point for each driver and the other have the end point for the drivers. Here is a snippet of this dataframe:

```
driver from to
0   1   0
0   2   1
0   4   5
0   5   2
1   1   3
1   2   1
1   5   2
1   7   5

starting = [4,7]
ending = [0,3]
```

In this example driver 0 should start at point 4 and end at point 0. If you follow on the dataframe. the 3rd row start at point 4 and goes to 5. Then the 4th row goes from 5 to 2. After that in the second row it goes from 2 to 1 and finally in the first row goes from 1 to 0 where it should end as we see in the list ending. For the second driver the dataframe happens to have the route sorted from the bottom to top. So in the last row it start at 7 until in the 5th row it reaches point 3.

My question is, is there a way to sort this dataframe first by driver- as I already did here, then the first first row for each driver would have the starting point for that driver in the column "from" followed by the row that "from" value is the "to" value from the pervious row until we reach the end of the route.

Here is how the final dataframe should look like:

```
driver from to
0   4   5
0   5   2
0   2   1
0   1   0
1   7   5
1   5   2
1   2   1
1   1   3
```

I hope I was able to explain how the final dataframe should be sorted.
I appreciate you help.

Comment: This is more complicated than a simple sorting operation.  Given a set of driver rows, it's certainly possible to put them in order, but you'd have to examine all of them to find the one "from" point that doesn't have a "to", so you know where to start.  Again, this is a case where pandas makes this more difficult -- it would be easier to do this before you convert to DataFrame.

Comment: You're looking for a path in a directed graph. I suggest looking at a graph library, such as networkx.